# How to pass internal function values as parameters to its callback

Tags: javascript, oop

Im sorry I don't know the exact wording so please bear with me. what Im trying to do is the same thing as we all do with the event listeners like so:

```
foo.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
})
```

with the example above I can access the `event` instance using the anonymous callback function. in my case, I have this simple function:

```
function post_rqst({ url, data = '', callback }) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        callback()
    }
    request.send(data)
}
```

now when I call the `post_rqst()`, I want to be able to access the `request` instance inside the callback definition like so:

```
post_rqst({
    url: 'foo.com/bar/',
    data: '[x,y,z]',
    callback: function(request) {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            console.log('done!')
        }
    }
})
```

Im a javascript newbie and I don't know what I don't know. thank you for your guidance in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass that `request` instance when you call `callback`, so instead of:

```
function post_rqst({ url, data = '', callback }) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        callback();
    };
    request.send(data);
}
```

You would have:

```
function post_rqst({ url, data = '', callback }) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.onload = function() {
        callback(request);
    };
    request.send(data);
}
```

Here you can see that in action using `setTimeout` to fake that request:

```js
function fakePost({ url, data = '', callback }) {
    const request = { url, data, method: 'POST' };
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(request);
    }, 1000);
}

fakePost({
  url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
  data: 'foobar',
  origin: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
  callback: (req) => {
    console.log('Callback received req =', req);
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks indeed, I'm still curious about how it works and I can't wrap my head around it. Are we passing a non-existent parameter to the function call? In Python there is a similar concept as *keyword arguments*, is this essentially the same thing?

Comment: In this code, you are defining a `post_rqst` function that takes a single argument. When you do `post_rqst({ url, data = '', callback })`, that's simply using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) to unpack the different properties on that object. Is that what you mean with the reference to Python's keyword arguments?

Comment: no actually it was a brain glitch, I wrongly thought that at the `request.onload = function() { callback(request) }` we are defining the `callback` function. my mistake, Im sorry for inconvenience.